# Resharper with COM interop complains "Cannot access internal constructor"

Tags: c#, resharper, com-interop

I have an OCX file built using VB6 that I'd like to access from C#.  So I added a reference to the OCX in a C# project, and then added code to instantiate an object from the OCX:

```
    var blah = new Blah();
```

This compiles just fine, without errors or warnings, and it seems to work as I would expect - I can call methods on the blah object and they seem to do what I would expect them to do.  However, if I go to ReSharper / Inspect / Code Issues in Solution, ReSharper complains that the above quoted line is a "C# Compiler Error", saying "Cannot access internal constructor 'BlahClass' here".

Since it's claiming it's a C# compiler error, yet it seems to compile (and in fact work) just fine, I'm guessing it's just an issue with ReSharper itself.  However, I'm pretty new to this, and I'd like to make sure.  Perhaps what I'm doing is not the correct way of instantiating an object from an OCX, or something like that?

I am using VS2012 Professional and ReSharper 7.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

The C# compiler looks at that coe and sees invocation of "dynamic" code (code whose objects may have new methods/properties available after execution started) and thus can't be sure that any particular method/property *isn't* there at compile time.  Resharper tries to help out a bit more by trying to figure out circumstances that might fail at runtime.  It may be using an out-dated description (type library) of that class to make its decision.  Or, that description of that class is out of sync with what the code actually does.  It's hard to tell solely based on what you've posted whether that's a good thing or a bad thing.  If "it works", it seems like a good thing; but that's very subjective--it could be a problem waiting to happen.

I would see this as suspicious and maybe contact the vendor to get reassurance there isn't something lurking in there that will cause problems later.